# Restricting tabbing through input field using JavaScript key code 9

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to prevent a user from using the tab key to tab through input boxes on a form with the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":input").on("keydown", noTab);
});

function noTab(evt){
    $(this).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 9)
            e.preventDefault();
    })
}
```

but it is not working as I am still able to use the tab key to tab through my input fields. I have a similar function for restricting a user from using the spacebar, which does work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":input").on("keydown", noSpace);
});

function noSpace(evt){
    // prevent user from entering a space
    $(this).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 32)
            e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

**EDIT: I'm using UIKit for the front end html**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `tabindex` to -1 to prevent tabbing to an `<input>` field:

```
<input type="text" tabindex="-1">
```

If you must use JavaScript/jQuery to change the `tabIndex` property after the page loads:

```js
$(':input').prop('tabIndex', -1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

Comment: +1 It did not work. I'm still able to use the tab key. BTW, I'm using UI Kit for the front end html. I neglected to mention this. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Did you see the demo? Can you reproduce your issue in a demo of your own?

Comment: +1 Thank you. Your solution works. I originally put the `tabindex="-1"` in the html which did not seem to work, but it works now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used jQuery to cancel the keydown event when Tab is being pressed. It's working fine for me in Chrome. Hope this helps!

```
$("input").keydown(function(e){
    if ((e.which || e.keyCode || e.charCode) == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/um55dm6u/)</kbd>